# Handling multiple models in a single view OS X application

Tags: macos, cocoa, model-view-controller

I have a design question. I am building the app below in the screenshot. I will use it to encrypt/decrypt with multiple algorithms like cesar shift, vigenere, etc.

As you see in the algorithm dropdown Caesar shift is selected, and so when the arrow is clicked the message is encrypted using the class model for the particular algorithm, it is all handled thru MVC pattern and all Iboutlets and button actions are wired up to the Window View Controller.

I am a bit unsure on how to do this the OOP way. I could have properties for all the models in the ViewController and then based on the selection have a CASE scenario for the models, but I think that would not be elegant.

Would it be wise to have a more view controllers for the other models, or that is asking for too much trouble? In my mind I don't see a need to have another viewcontroller since the only item that changes is the encryption algorithm model. Thanks in advance!

[image: Cipher App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need in additional ViewControllers. ViewController is related to your View in your case it's 1 to 1 relation. ViewController can handle a few models and it's ok.

As an additional advice, I can recommend to check [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern for creation of your encrypting algorithms (and related models).

Comment: This is exactly what I what thinking in my mind. Just didn't know how to explain it well. I guess I really need to delve into a patterns book. Factory pattern makes sense for my problem. Thanks!